# How to run a WUBI Ubuntu installation from VMware fusion?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, boot-camp, wubi

I have a Mac, running OSX as my host OS. I have a Boot Camp partition, which contains a WUBI install of Ubuntu.

Is there some way that I can run the WUBI install of Ubuntu through VMware fusion, so that I don't have to boot into Boot Camp? I can see the 17GB root.disk and 200MB swap.disk files, is there some way of getting VMware to mount them and boot from them?

Comment: do you specifically have to use WUBI? (coz i dont think that would be possible) or just that you want to run ubuntu in VMware

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so.  AFAIK, WUBI basically builds a partition inside the host.  I thought WUBI was Windows only...

Anyway, if you have a regular install of ubuntu (it has it's own partition), then this shouldn't be a problem.  What you're trying to do is use a raw disk partition.  You'll have to hack it a little though.  Here are a couple links about that:

- http://fearandloath.us/vmware-fusion-bootcamp-partition.html- seems to work
- http://communities.vmware.com/thread/104745- discussion that lists several other links